# How can I prevent users input to be cloned in the appended input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I insert some thing in the input box of module 1 and click add module button to clone the required elements that I need it clones also the inserted input I've tried to prevent that using event.preventDefault(); but it's still copying the input box with the inserted input from module 1 however, I can't clear it using the clear button that is located in the input box moreover the appended select options doesn't work and when I select an option it doesn't change.

Here is my demo of what's happening:-

http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/6/

and here is my javascript code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Sadd").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
    var $newLabel = $("#module-1-label").clone();
    var $newSc = $("#module-1-scredit").clone();
    var $newSgrade = $("#module-1-sgrade").clone();
    $newLabel.html("<h1>Module " + (lastId+1) + ":</h1>");
    $newSc.find("label").attr("for", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
    $newSc.find("input").attr("name", "Sc"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
    $newSgrade.find("label").attr("for", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
    $newSgrade.find("select").attr("name", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
    $("#modules").append($newLabel, $newSc, $newSgrade);
 });
 $("#Sremove").click(function() {
   var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
   if(lastId > 5){
      var lastLi = $("#modules h1").last().closest("li");
      var lastLi2 = lastLi.next("li");
      var lastLi3 = lastLi2.next("li");
      lastLi.remove();
      lastLi2.remove();
      lastLi3.remove();   
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are making life hard for yourself by (a) not having each module in a containing wrapper; (b) not having a template from which all modules including the initial five, are cloned; (c) unnecessary `id` and `for` attributes. Get the HTML right and creating a new module should boil down to a single line.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 if there is a sample that I can follow it will be helpful

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/20/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val("")` on the new input to clear the data in on the clone
or do `$(clone).find('input').val("");` if there is more than one input

In your case with the select box you need to add the following lines
After you declare (or on the same line) the variables

```
var $newSc = $("#module-1-scredit").clone().find('input').val("");
var $newSgrade = $("#module-1-sgrade").clone().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$newSgrade.find('option[value="-1"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Edit: Had to handle the reselection of the select due to default value being "-1" however you may need to look at the cloning of this select element. Perhaps on the page have the blank question hidden and just clone that.

Comment: the $newSc.find('input').val(""); worked fine but the clear button that is located in the appended input box doesn't clear when I enter some input and I have to do it using back space. For the select box I've added .removeAttr("selected"); but still I can't even choose option and if I choose an option from module 1 for example "A" and then add a new module it will copy the exact option that I have chosen and I can't change it after that

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with some code, could you tell me how it's working now?

Comment: fiddle is not updated and here what I get when I add your lines http://i.imgur.com/9VgBmFk.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/19/ Check out what I've done here. You need to look into triggering the select box to update so It clear the previous , chosen selects clear something like `.chosen({updated:true});` or something along those lines